# Docusign custom fields via api from salesforce

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am using docusign rest api in salesforce. I have created template in docusign and added custom field in it which is related to Salesforce object's field.

I want to populate that field while creating envelope using template via docusign rest api. Please let me know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request using a template and **Custom Fields**.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Envelope with custom fields",
    "status": "created",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "A71FC458-E234-42FF-9385-E672C4EFD436"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "customFields": {
                        "textCustomFields": [
                            {
                                "name": "MyOwnTextField",
                                "required": "true",
                                "show": "true",
                                "value": "MyValue"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want to populate custom fields which I added in the template to be populated by salesforce field value

Comment: Can you please add your api request to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sample request to populate all the account fields on template.

```
{
"emailSubject": "Envelope with custom fields",
"status": "created",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "A71FC458-E234-42FF-9385-E672C4EFD436"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "customFields": {
                    "textCustomFields": [
                        {
                            "configurationType": "salesforce",
                            "name": "Account",
                            "required": "true",
                            "show": "true",
                            "value": "[SALESFORCE_ACCOUNT_RECORD_ID]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

```
This allows us to populate all the account fields present in template. 
Like this you can use for any object custom fields present in template.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following response applies only to DocuSign REST API using JSON/XML:
You can create one or more merge fields in your template.
Use the 'GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes' endpoint
If you plan on using multiple templates in the same envelope then the code in the above two responses is correct.
You can instead provide a simpler JSON if you only have one template per envelope. Replace the Composite Tempaltes/Server Templates/Inline Templates nodes, and just provide a TemplateId in the top node of the JSON and add a new node at the top level in the following format to specify the Salesforce ID (in my example, and opportunity):

```
   "customFields":{  
      "textCustomFields":[  
         {  
            "value":"0060n00000DIvfNAAT",
            "name":"Opportunity",
            "configurationType":"salesforce"
         }
      ]
   }
```